# Can we hide glyphicons using hidden="hidden"

Tags: css, html, glyphicons

Can we hide a glyphicon icon like this,

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" 
         title="Insert an appropriate value" id="author" hidden="hidden"></i> 
<p>Author</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but using ONLY <s>`hidden`</s> will be an *invalid attribute*, so use `data-hidden="hidden"` as it's valid to create custom attributes as of HTML5, but they should've [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) prefix.

And then in your CSS, you can write..

```
[data-hidden="hidden"] {
   display: none; /* OR */
   visibility: hidden; /* If you want to reserve space */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k84vd/)

---

If you are damn sure that you will be using this to hide elements, and ONLY hide, than consider using `!important` so that specificity doesn't trouble you.